# Autocomplete jQueryUI double call function on select and press enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'd like some little help.
Here's my JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Mirawen/q59nqh2z/

```
function keyPress(keyEvent)
{  
  if (keyEvent.which == 13)
    MainFunction();
}

function MainFunction()
{
  alert("Hello World");
}

var arrSource = ["foo", "foooo", "foooooo", "bar", "barr", "barr"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
    source: arrSource,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui)
    {
      MainFunction(); 
    }
  });
});
```

When I press enter, I want to call `MainFunction()`, and also call this function when I select an item from autocomplete
The point is, when I select an item and press enter, `MainFunction()` is called twice.
I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that I solve my issue !

In my MainFunction(), I've an AJAX call (ASP.NET) with async false. I tried to change this call async to true. Now, only the event `autocompleteselect` is triggered !
But, I don't have any clue why `keypress`isn't triggered anymore. I'll keep looking, and edit this answer if I find why async false also trigger `keypress` after `autocompleteselect`, in case if someone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are calling the same function twice on same event,so it is calling main function twice. Even if you press enter it is a keypress/keyup/keydown event. So, when document is ready, it is getting called already once and gets called on your enter keypress event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addEnterKeyHandler()
{ 
 $( "#txtSearch" ).keypress(function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
       MainFunction();
    }
  });
}

function removeEnterKeyHandler(){
 $('#txtSearch').unbind("keypress");
}

function MainFunction()
{
 alert("Hello World");
}

var arrSource = ["foo", "foooo", "foooooo", "bar", "barr", "barr"];

$(document).ready(function() {
 addEnterKeyHandler();
  $("#txtSearch").autocomplete(
    {
        source: arrSource,
        minLength: 1,
        selecting: function(event, ui){         
         canPressEnter = false;
          
        },
        select: function (event, ui)
        {
         removeEnterKeyHandler();
          MainFunction();
          addEnterKeyHandler();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-xNjb53/rY+WmG+4L6tTl9m6PpqknWZvRt0rO1SRnJzw="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css">

<div>
  <input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeypress="keyPress(event);" />
  <button type="button" title="Search" onclick="MainFunction();">Search
  </button>
</div>
```